# Lag from BufferedReader

Tags: java, performance

I am having trouble finding the source of lag in my code. I believe I have narrowed the possible source down to this method.

Essentially I start a script, set it in a `Process` variable `p`, and grab the output from the script using a `BufferedReader`, and put it into an `ArrayList`.

Somehow I am getting lag when the script outputs (it outputs at a 5 minute interval)

Any ideas?

```
    public void runCommand(String path)
    {
        if (SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS)
        {
            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "cd " + path + " && " + this.getCommand());

            builder.redirectErrorStream(true);

            try
            {
                p = builder.start();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                String name = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName();
                String pid = name.substring(0, name.indexOf("@"));

                p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./btrace.sh " + pid + " " + path + " " + this.getConfig().getPort());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;

        try
        {
            // Print out everything that's happening.
            while (true)
            {
                line = r.readLine();

                if (line == null)
                {
                    break;
                }

                if (this.isDebugEnabled)
                {
                    System.out.println("[Script Output]: " + line);
                }

                lines.add(line);
            }

            r.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is lag on both Windows and Linux? --- Any reason you don't think `redirectErrorStream(true)` is needed on Linux? --- Any reason you use `cd` instead of the `ProcessBuilder.directory(File directory)` method?

Comment: You need to make sure you are reading from both InputStream and ErrorStream in case you are not using `ProcessBuilder`. If the process called wants to write into the error stream, it may block if you don't read the data off the stream

Comment: Tested on Linux.

Would not reading the error stream cause issues with lag?

Comment: You need to read both streams otherwise the process you are starting can't write to them anymore and will block.

Comment: Oh ok. How can I read both streams? By doing redirectErrorStream?

Comment: Yes. Make sure also to close the process's input stream. The only 'lag' here comes from the process itself. It has nothing to do with `BufferedReader`.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like I found the cause of lag.

After researching how ArrayLists resize, I realized it could be performance taxing and tried using a Linked list.

So far seems like the issue is fixed.

Thanks!

Comment: I am testing it and it does seem like it.

ArrayLists resize by half Everytime you add to them. I add the output line by line so it goes from 10 -> 15, etc.

Everytime it does it clones the current one, and if there's a lot of output it causes lag. LinkedLists don't work the same way so it's not cloned everytime I add to it

Comment: Allocating an array of references is negligible compared to the allocation of the lines themselves. In any case it's very hard to believe that you are noticing pauses because of memory allocation unless your heap is full and the GC is under a lot of pressure. Note that LinkedList will use more memory than an ArrayList. As suggested in your answer comments, try to always consume both output streams of the process and close stdin. This will avoid having the process blocked.

Comment: Suppose I add 100,000 lines one by one like in the while loop I have above

Wouldn't that be a strain using an ArrayList? That would mean the whole thing was cloning itself repeatedly until it had enough space for every line

Comment: No, the amortized insertion cost in a ArrayList is low and scales well. More info here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array. Some numbers: https://dzone.com/articles/benchmarking-java-lists-performance. This is micro-performance details, not related to the lag you report.